# Stack columns from multiple CSV's into a master file

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I am trying to take many CSV's and stack the column data into one file using the headers to 
align the data. The headers are not always in the right order and some are missing but there are matches between the files.

EG.

```
File 1:

Stuff   More_Stuff   Lots_stuff 
0       2             1
2       3             2 
4                     3  


File 2:     

Stuff   Lots_Stuff   More_stuff good_Stuff
6       4             3         1
8       5             4 
10


Master File

Stuff  More_stuff    Lots_Stuff  good_stuff
0       2             1          1
2       3             2
4       3             3
6       4             4
8                     5
10
```

The csv's are all in a folder -> /*.csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to create a list of all the csvs using os.listdir or glob, loop through the list and read each csv into a dataframe and then use the concat function to merge them all into one long dataframe. pandas.concat() is header aware and will automatically align the headers for you. You can then output the dataframe to a csv.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

globbed_files = glob.glob("*.csv") #creates a list of all csv files

data = [] # pd.concat takes a list of dataframes as an agrument
for csv in globbed_files:
    frame = pd.read_csv(csv)
    data.append(frame)

bigframe = pd.concat(data, ignore_index=True) #dont want pandas to try an align row indexes
bigframe.to_csv("output.csv")
```

Comment: Instead of creating a list, you could create a blank dataframe - pd.DataFrame(), then concat the frame within the loop. Not sure it will be hugely faster, but will narrow down the lines of code.

Comment: Is there anyway to do this without holding the entire end Dataframe in memory? I have quite a few csv's with a large amount of data in each, Python is eating up to 1.5GB of ram

Comment: You could read and tokenize the first lines of all your csvs and then place them into a `set` to get the unique headers. Those headers would be used as the keys for `csv.Dictwriter` in the csv module to write to an output file. Each csv would then be read in and appended to the output csv file using the dictwriter. It's a lot more fiddly then the pandas solution but wont chew up loads of memory.